# Couldn't allocate RandomX cache

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, daemon

Using a new install of GUI version 0.18.1.2 - Fluorine Fermi - I've downloaded the blockchain onto an old MacBook Pro (macOS High Sierra 10.13) with a 500GB SSD and 8GB of RAM (the maximum I can install on it).

However, I'm finding that the daemon fails to start.

When running monerod, I get "couldn't allocate RandomX cache".

I'd hoped to dedicate this old MacBook solely to running a Monero node, but am I correct in thinking that's it's just too old for the task? Is there anything else I could try on this MacBook which might work?

Comment: Do you know how to start `monerod` from the terminal? In that case, you should be able to resolve the issue with the command listed here: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/8504#issuecomment-1221334721 | Please let me know if you need further instructions.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I'm not overly confident with with CLI / Terminal. I've been opening monerod simply by opening it from within its folder in Finder. I'm keen to follow further instructions for how to do use the terminal using the command you linked to, if you're happy to provide additional hand-holding?

Comment: All right. Please try as follows. First, open `Spotlight` (the search feature), search for `Terminal`, and open it. Second, open `Finder` and browse to the directory of `monerod`. Third, drag `monerod` into the terminal. The terminal should now display the path of `monerod` . Fourth, in front of the path, add `cd ` (make sure there is a space between `cd` and the rest of the path. Fifth, remove `monerod` from the path, so the path is basically the folder of `monerod`. Sixth, hit enter, the terminal should now switch to the directory of `monerod`. Seventh, type `ls -al` to verify [1/2]

Comment: that you're in the correct directory (the list should show `monerod`). Lastly, in the terminal, type `MONERO_RANDOMX_UMASK=8 ./monerod` to start the daemon (monerod).

Comment: I have followed your instructions and they have worked perfectly. The wallet and the daemon are now synchronised. Many thanks indeed. Just to clarify, each time I need to start monerod, I will need to do it from the terminal from now onwards? Is there a way to suggest that this issue could be addressed in a later version of the GUI wallet or is it too rare to bother with?

Comment: Great to hear! Yes, every time you start `monerod`, it has to be done from the terminal with the `MONERO_RANDOMX_UMASK=8 ./monerod` command. There's an open issue for the bug on the [Monero Github](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/8504), I presume in the future a pull request will be created to resolve it (and then you should be able to simply run the daemon (monerod) from the GUI directly).

Comment: I have encountered the same issue but with the Windows 64 bit executable. I do not see the way to implement running MONERO_RANDOMX_UMASK=8 while envoking monerod.exe I have done everything to allow huge pages and am running the terminal as Administrator as well allocated monerod.exe to run as Admin in properties. Any idea how to envoke the same command but not in Linux terms? for instance I am envoking now with monerod.exe --config-file C:\Monero\monero-windows-10-x64-v0.18.1.2\bin\monerod.conf all is running fine but with warning 2023-02-12 11:28:56.661 W Couldn't allocate RandomX light VM us